# Is the Eigenvector in Column space of $A-\lambda I$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For given a real matrix $A$ of size $n$ by $n$, we assume that there exist $\lambda$ with multiplicity $2$ and its corresopnding eigenvector is denoted by $x$.
In this situation, prove that

if the dimension of the null space of $A-\lambda I$ is $1$, then $x$ belongs to the column space of $A-\lambda I$.

---

Actually, I tried many times, but I failed to prove this.
Can someone let me know the proof? Some hints is also very thank you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenspace  corresponding to the eigenvalue of multiplicity 2 cannot be the nullspace which has dimension 1 so $\lambda$ is not= 0 . Thus Ax = $\lambda$x and so x=(1/$\lambda$)Ax  which is in the column space .

Comment: I am very sorry that I do not understand your answer. First of all, what is $\lambda |=0$?

Comment: If $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\lambda & c\\ 0 &\lambda\end{array}\right]$, since $A$ is an upper triangular matrix, the eigenvalues are easily found as $\lambda$ with multiplicity $2$.

From $A-2I=\left[\begin{array}{CC}0&c\\0&0\end{array}\right]$, we know

* The rank of $A-2I$ is $1$.
* The nullity of $A-2I$ is $2-1=1$.
* The nullspace of $A-2I$, denoted by $N(A-2I)$, is the span of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

I think eigenspace is $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}c\\0\end{bmatrix}:c\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$, which is the nullspace, isn't it?

Comment: Your formula's for A and A-2 I are wrong  . Multiplicity and eigenvalue are not the same .